# How to avoid ClassCastException on count() of JPARepository

Tags: spring-boot

My  Service

```
 @Cacheable(cacheResolver = CachingConfiguration.CACHE_RESOLVER_NAME)
  public long countElement() {
    return repository.count();
 }
```

My RestController

```
  @ApiOperation(value = "Returns total count of elements")
  @GetMapping(value = "/element/count", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public long countElements() {
    logger.info("Count elements");
    return service.countElement();
  }
```

For my repository I extend JpaRepository.

For some reasons sometimes on a count request my application produce

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

This happens in the RestController line.

```
 return service.countElement();
```

Why this happen? As you can see the return type is long not HashSet. Any Ideas how to fix it?

StackTrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at de.myapp.rest.services.AnalyseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e53ae01.countElement(<generated>)
    at de.myapp.rest.controller.GenericRestApiController.countElements(GenericRestApiController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
```

Comment: post your stacktrace as well

Comment: can you test it without cache , I guess cache is having different data.

Comment: @Shailesh after I removed caching, the exception is gone. I figured it out that my app with caching uses always the Datatype of first request. Example 1. getAllElements: HashSet  2. count()  <---- this fail cause the return type is still HashSet

Comment: Thats they purpose of caching,  cache the response of first request and serve subsequent request with cached data, main reason for your problem is you are not putting any caching-key on methods